# CSS - Color divs intersection

Tags: html, css, intersection, overlap

I was wondering if a solution exists in pure CSS to color the intersection between two divs.

For exemple, if I have two divs, with the same class like this:

```
<div class="orange_square"></div>
<div class="blue_square"></div>
```

They are placed on the page so they so they overlap, like this:

[image]

I want the intersection of these two divs to be colored in red, and this in CSS only. I was wondering if something like this existed:

```
.orange_square {
   background-color:orange;
}
.blue_square {
   background-color:blue;
}
.orange_square [overlap_operator?] .blue_square {
   background-color:red;
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: did you try giving some alpha to orange, make it translucent

Comment: yeah but that's not really what I want unfortunately :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Unfortunately, not in 'Pure CSS'

(sorry)

### However...

Although there isn't a way to *automatically* calculate & define define such a area *purely* in CSS, if you know the dimensions of the two 'parent' `divs`, you can hard code it without adding additional DOM clutter, which is going to be as close as you can get just using CSS and `div` elements:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/mGtYE/)

HTML

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
div:first-of-type {
    background:orange;
}
div:last-of-type:before {
    content:'';
    height:33px;
    width:33px;
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    background:red;
}
div:last-of-type {
    background:lightblue;
    top:75px;
    left:75px;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants something like *color combination* which is very dynamic, such as if changing the orange to blue, the intersected region should have another color than the fixed `red`.

Comment: @KingKing - absolutely, as noted in the answer - although they as requested 'in pure CSS' there isnt a way as far as I'm aware

Comment: In fact, I just want a way to detect when two divs overlap. Then, I would be able to color it as I want. I'm making a timeline with events (colored divs) and I want to color in red when tow events overlap in my timeline. But it seems like it's not possible in pure CSS. I'm pretty sure that I will achieve this in JS but a pure CSS solution would have been wonderful ^^ Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @PiTiNiNjA - sadly, this isnt possible without resorting to JS

Answer (score 5):

You can try the `mix-blend-mode` property.

```css
.orange_square,
.blue_square {
    position:absolute;
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}

.orange_square {
    background: orange;
}

.blue_square {
    background: blue;
    top:75px;
    left:55px;
    
    /* the trick */
    mix-blend-mode: color-burn;
}
```

```html
<div class="orange_square"></div>
<div class="blue_square"></div>
```

Tip: always check the compatibility table https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mixblendmode

Comment: that's very useful thx i didn't know this property !