# CSS How to change color in section where two items overlap?

Tags: css

```html
<div class="circle" style="top:75px;left:75px;background:#7B3F61;"></div>
<div class="circle" style="top:75px;left:175px;background:#E78481;"></div>

<style>  
  .circle {position:absolute;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    border-radius:50%;}
  body{background: #09042A;}
</style>
```

I'm trying to get the section where the second circle div overlaps the first one, to change color, and the color I want to use is the background color. So the effect would look like where both circles meet, they cancel each other and all you see is the background.

I have been thinking how to go about this but I just can't figure it out, can someone help me?

Comment: mix-blend-mode: exclusion; on the second div?

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740740/css-color-divs-intersection#23740830

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mix-blend-mode: color-burn;` property in your case.

```html
<div class="circle" style="top:75px;left:75px;background:#7B3F61;"></div>
<div class="circle" style="top:75px;left:175px;background:#E78481;"></div>

<style>
  .circle {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    mix-blend-mode: color-burn;
  }
  
  body {
    background: #09042A;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: we see nothing in chrome

Answer (score 0):

color the second circle with a `radial-gradient` having the same position/size as the first circle:

```css
.circle {
  position: fixed;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  top: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.first {
  left: 75px;
  background: #7B3F61;
}

.second {
  left: 175px;
  transition:1s;
  background: 
   radial-gradient(farthest-side,#09042A 99%,transparent) 
   75px 50px/ /* position */
   150px 150px /* size*/
   no-repeat fixed  #E78481;
}
body:hover .second {
  left:50px;
}
body {
  background: #09042A;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle first"></div>
<div class="circle second"></div>
```

Comment: That is amazing, I had come across radial gradient in the past, just a simple example.
But your example with the animation is so much more detailed. Any links to good places to study further on it?

Comment: @S2000fred I don't have any particular link but I would invite you to check some of my previous answers around radial-gradients (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8620333+%5Bradial-gradients%5D) where you can find more tricks